# Add child stories to EPIC story cardboard

Tags: rally

I have created a board of EPIC stories filtered by target release using Rally App SDK. I would like to display child stories info (Formatted ID and Name) for each epic story in the board and I'm not sure how to do that. Anyone know of a simple way to add this to each of the cards? Please see my code below:

```
            _onLoad: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                    types: ['User Story'],
                    attribute: 'ScheduleState',
                    readOnly: true,
                    context: this.getContext(),
                    cardConfig: {
                        editable: false,
                        showIconsAndHighlightBorder: false,
                        fields: ['Name', 'TestCases', 'c_StoryType', 'Children', 'c_TargetRelease', 'PlanEstimate']
                    },
                    storeConfig: {
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'c_StoryType',
                                value: 'SAGA Feature'
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'c_TargetRelease',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: this.down('rallyfieldvaluecombobox').getValue()
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            _onSelect: function() {
                var board = this.down('rallycardboard');
                board.refresh({
                    storeConfig: {
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'c_StoryType',
                                value: 'SAGA Feature'
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'c_TargetRelease',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: this.down('rallyfieldvaluecombobox').getValue()
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifying things you want to show on card in `cardConfig`

```
cardConfig: {   
    fields: [
        'Name', 
        'TestCases', 
        'c_StoryType', 
        'Children', 
        'c_TargetRelease', 
        'PlanEstimate'  
        { name: 'Children', renderer: this._renderChildStories },
    ],
}
```

and then define `_renderChildStories` function,
I thing `value` will be a collection of child stories, so you can loop that depending upon the `val` value

```
_renderChildStories: function(val) {
    var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store',{
        data: [
            {
                'FormattedID': val.get('FormattedID'),
                'Name': val.get('Name')
            }
        ]
    });
    return store
}
```